# C# Outlook 2013 Addin Accessing Explorer

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin, explorer

Is it possible to access Explorer to check for the existence of certain folders, and create folders if necessary from an outlook addin?   If so what API/interface is used to do so from outlook.  The MAPIFolder seems to be just for the outlook folders.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:  To clarify, I'm talking about OS folder that are not part of outlook.  The particular folders I'm speaking of are actually on a file server in the domain.  Which is mapped to the users computer who would be using the addin.  Will the fact the he is a domain user and already authenticated mean I wont run into any issue when trying to access the filesystem from the addin?

Comment: You can't use `System.IO.Directory.Exists(string)` or `System.IO.File.Exists(string)`? See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory(v=vs.110).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @RonBeyer this needs to be done via the Outlook Object Model - its not file system. Shenk are you working with VSTO or VBA?

Comment: Are you talking about Outlook or OS folders?

Comment: OS folders, VSTO in C#

Comment: Would the functions @RonBeyer suggested work if they are OS folders?  Or do I need to stick with the MAPIFolder interface?  I thought MAPI was just for the outlook folders one would have on their account.

Comment: @shenk it wouldn't be that hard to test, I can't make a VSTO on my installation but I can't imagine it would take more than 10 minutes to set up a quick test project. The ones I posted are specifically for the file system, not MAPI.

Comment: Yeah I know they will work for the FS, but my concern is whether accessing the network drive in the domain would require something extra if done from an outlook addin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use System.IO.* class for checking whether a folder exists or not. For example, the [Exists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists(v=vs.110).aspx) method of the Directory or File classes from the System.IO namespace determines whether the given path refers to an existing directory/file on disk:

```
        if(File.Exists(path)) 
        {
            // This path is a file
            ProcessFile(path); 
        }               
        else if(Directory.Exists(path)) 
        {
            // This path is a directory
            ProcessDirectory(path);
        }
        else 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is not a valid file or directory.", path);
        }
```

Comment: I'm going to test it myself when I'm back at my desk, but do you know if accessing a network drive in a domain this way would be an issue?  The user is already logged in as the computer is joined to the domain.  I would assume there would no issue as it should act just like a local directory since it is mapped but I'm not 100% on that.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need the Explorer object for that? It is just for *displaying* Outlook folders.

You can check if a particular folder existing `MAPIFolder.Folders.Item("sub folder name")` using the parent folder object. If the folder with the given name does not exist, an exception will be raised (which your code will need to trap)

To add a new folder, use `MAPIFolder.Folders.Add("sub folder name")`

Comment: By explorer I meant folders you would access via windows explorer.  I need to check for the existence of a folder that isn't part of outlook before I save something there,  Will that work for folders that aren't part of outlook as in not the inbox, sent, etc.?

Comment: Yes. Where is the folder that you need to check located relative to other folder, such as the Inbox?

Comment: The folder i need to check is outside of outlook in a mapped network drive.

Comment: Then this really has nothing to do with Outlook. In C# you can use the Directory.Exists() method - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists(v=vs.110).aspx